# Mysql unique rows based on one column value by one+faster query

Tags: mysql

How can I get unique rows from a mysql table based on value of one column?(See below the screenshot, I want to get unique rows of this table based on entry_id field)

[image: Screenshot of data]

I want a query which will produce following result.

```
----------------------
entry_id | comment_id
----------------------
   380        4716
   371        4723
```

FYI, table name is comments. (My goal is to get latest comment(last one) for each entries). I'm aware that this can't be achieved using DISTINCT or group by.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: comment_id seems unique ?

Comment: Have you considered using a subquery to find out which values are not unique and excluding them from the result set?

Comment: Could you please specify, whether what you need is distinct values of a chosen column ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Your rows table already unique actually..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only entry_id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry_id FROM table WHERE ...
```

Or if you need select many columns you should do that:

```
SELECT entry_id, comment_id ... FROM table WHERE ... GROUP BY entry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query served my purpose(If somebody face similar issue)

```
SELECT entry_id, MAX(comment_id) AS comment_id FROM comments GROUP BY `entry_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select entry_id ,
   (select comment_id from comments t1 
   where t1.entry_id= t2.entry_id 
   order by comment_id desc 
   limit 1) 'comment_id'
from comments t2;
```